# Выталкивание первого элемента

Tags: css, css3

Здравствуйте, вот есть блок с текстом и заголовком внутри который выровнен по правую сторону:

```css
h1{
    float: right;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
    <div>
    23123 123 132 123 123 123 123 132 123
<h1>211 123 123 123 2312 123</h1>
</div>
```

Как заставить при сужении блока выталкиваться не заголовок а текст в блоке?

Comment: что должно случиться не понял вопроса

Comment: А можете как-то пояснить что вам надо? Пока это неясно.

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov Aприори всегда последний элемент выталкивается, и стилями этого не изменить?

Comment: @PeGaS А вы можете как-то по другому пояснить? Чтобы я понял вас. Может даже картинки привести как получается и как хочется.  И как-то непонятно: выбранный ответ решил ваш вопрос или нет? Если да, то как? Потому что я не вижу разницы между результатом кода того, что в вопросе и ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div {
  text-align: right
}

div h1 {
  background: red;
  display: inline-table;
}

div div {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>211 123 123 123 2312 123</h1>
  <div>23123 123 132 123 123 123 123 132 123</div>
</div>
```

Comment: То есть априори всегда последний элемент выталкивается, и стилями этого не изменить?